# Remove a route from a routee and get poison pill?

Tags: java, akka

I have an actor who is routing messages to a group of other actors who act as wrappers on top of a volatile service. So far everythign is great, but I'd like to be able to control how many actors exist acting on this service (since they may represent socket connections or other physical properties) so beign able to manage scaling them would be nice.

I see that there is a remove routee method on the router and it does remove the routes, but is there a way to send a poison pill to my child actors first before they are removed?  The docs say that a poison pill message should come through when removing the routee this way but I'm not seeing that happen.

I have code like this

```
final Collection<Routee> routees = JavaConversions.asJavaCollection(router.routees());

for (final Routee routee : routees.stream()
                                  .limit(numberToRemove)
                                  .collect(toList())) {

    router = router.removeRoutee(routee);
}
```

Comment: I think that the `removeRoutee` method internally sends a `PoisonPill` to the specified `Routee`. What exactly you want to achieve? What do you mean by *is there a way to send a poison pill to my child actors first before they are removed* more precisely?

Comment: I thought it would too, but it doesn't look to. So basically it will stop tracking the route but the actor is still active. Which makes sense, since I could re-use it for something else.  It looks like I need to just get a reference to the actor ref from the router list and manually send it a poison pill, have the context unwatch it, and remove it from the routing list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like I was missing the fact that I had to send a poison pill manually in order to stop my router. Here is a full scala demo app

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing._

case class Add()

case class Remove()

class Worker(id: Integer) extends UntypedActor {
  println(s"Made worker $id")

  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception]) override
  def preStart(): Unit = {
    println(s"Starting $id")
  }

  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception]) override
  def postStop(): Unit = {
    println(s"Stopping $id")
  }

  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def onReceive(message: Any): Unit = message match {
    case _ => println(s"Message received on actor $id")
  }
}

class Master extends Actor {

  var count = 0

  def makeWorker() = {
    val id = count

    count = count + 1

    context.actorOf(Props(new Worker(id)))
  }

  var activeWorkers = Seq.fill(2) {
    makeWorker()
  }

  var router = Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), activeWorkers.map(r => {
    context watch r
    ActorRefRoutee(r)
  }).toIndexedSeq)

  def receive = {
    case Remove =>
      println("Removing route")

      val head = router.routees.head.asInstanceOf[ActorRefRoutee].ref

      head ! PoisonPill

      context unwatch head

      router = router.removeRoutee(head)

      printRoutes()


    case Add =>
      println("Adding route")

      val worker = makeWorker()

      context watch worker

      router = router.addRoutee(worker)

      printRoutes()


    case w: AnyRef =>

      printRoutes()

      router.route(w, sender())
  }

  def printRoutes(): Unit ={
    val size = router.routees.size

    println(s"Total routes $size")
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  var system = ActorSystem.create("foo")

  var master = system.actorOf(Props[Master])

  master ! "foo"

  master ! Remove

  master ! "foo"

  master ! "bar"

  master ! Add

  master ! "biz"
}
```